# Azure Pipelines Docker Compose to AWS ECR

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I have a project that contains 4 apis:

- logapi
- fileapi
- userapi
- applicationapi

This is the yaml I have on my Azure Pipelines:

```
steps:
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Docker Compose Build'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerComposeFileArgs: |
     NETWORK=dev-network
     DOCKER_REGISTRY-=dev-
    projectName: 'api_core'
    action: 'Build services'
    includeSourceTags: true

steps:
- task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.ECRPushImage.ECRPushImage@1
  displayName: 'Push Image: Api_Core'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS Service Connection'
    regionName: 'ap-southeast-1'
    sourceImageName: 'dev-logapi'
    sourceImageTag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    repositoryName: 'number.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev-api_core'
    autoCreateRepository: true
  enabled: false
```

However, when I run the process, I get this error:

Error response from daemon: No such image: dev-logapi:2742

How can I get the correct image?

Answer (score 0):

That's is because you are not pushing your image after building it, furthermore, **you need to pull the image which you pushed previously into your registry IF you are consuming it from another job**, in the example below the steps are contained into the same job, thus we don't need to pull them again, the first one will build and the second one will push the image.

```
job:
steps:
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: Build services
  inputs:
    action: Build services
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
    azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
    dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
    projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
    qualifyImageNames: true
    additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
    dockerComposeFileArgs: |
      firstArg=$(firstArg)
      secondArg=$(secondArg)

- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: Push services
  inputs:
    action: Push services
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
    azureContainerRegistry: $(azureContainerRegistry)
    dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
    projectName: $(Build.Repository.Name)
    qualifyImageNames: true
    additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
```

However in your code it looks like the second task is being executed from another job, it won't work as one job might fall under a different agent.
By definition Agents don't share the same context.